# Is it possible to trigger send transaction from NodeJs server for safe wallet without owner private key and owner get the notification for signing

Tags: gnosis-safe, private-key, multisignature, safe-core-sdk

I want to create a NodeJs server and use the safe sdk wallet to create the safe Instance and initiate the transaction from it, and then send the notification to all owners so that they can sign the transaction.In all these process, I do not want to use the any private keys.
here is the some code flow that tried -

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import Safe, { EthersAdapter } from '@safe-global/protocol-kit'

try{
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://soft-boldest-haze.ethereum-goerli.discover.quiknode.pro/15492b628879325f037838631cf5f1dd74babc6f/"); // Replace with your JSON-RPC URL
 
const safeOwner1 = provider.getSigner('owner1')
const safeOwner2 = provider.getSigner('owner2')

const ethAdapter1 = new EthersAdapter({
  ethers,
  signerOrProvider: safeOwner1
})
const ethAdapter2 = new EthersAdapter({
  ethers,
  signerOrProvider: safeOwner2
})
const amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.01', "ether");

const safeSdk1 = await Safe.default.create({ ethAdapter: ethAdapter1, safeAddress: "safeaddress" })
const safeTransactionData = {
    to: 'toaddress',
    value: amount.toString(),
    data: '0x'
  }
  const safeTransaction = await safeSdk1.createTransaction({ safeTransactionData })
  
   const safeSdk2 = await safeSdk1.connect({ ethAdapter: ethAdapter2, safeAddress: "safe address" })
const txHash = await safeSdk2.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction)
const approveTxResponse = await safeSdk2.approveTransactionHash(txHash)
console.log("wait approve", approveTxResponse)
await approveTxResponse.transactionResponse?.wait()

  const executeTxResponse = await safeSdk2.executeTransaction(safeTransaction)
  console.log("execute", executeTxResponse)
await executeTxResponse.transactionResponse?.wait()

  
  console.log({executeTxResponse})
}catch(Err){
  console.log("Er", Err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For signing of the transaction , it is neccesary to sign the transaction by th e owners . For this they require their private keys to sign it otherwise its impossobile to do so.